# Trivial and non-trivial zeros

Tags: z-transform, transfer-function, poles-zeros, zeros

I am new to DSP, and I'm self studying. Could someone please explain to me what do we mean by trivial and non-trivial zeros?

Comment: Could you give a reference that uses these terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't familiar with that term in the context of signal processing. (Instead, I've seen the term being used in the context of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).) But I've found a [document](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs206/archive/spring02/lab.dir/Lab9/lab9_v3_0_release.pdf) and [this book](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Designing_Audio_Effect_Plug_ins_in_C++_w.html?id=v0ulUYdhgXYC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) where the term is used in a DSP context. The (obvious) definition is that *trivial* poles and zeros are the ones at the origin $z=0$ and at infinity $|z|=\infty$. They're called trivial because they don't affect the magnitude of the corresponding frequency response. Multiplying a given $\mathcal{Z}$-transform with $z$ (i.e. adding a pole at infinity and a zero at the origin) just advances the corresponding sequence by one sample, and multiplying by $z^{-1}$ (i.e., adding a pole at the origin and a zero at infinity) delays the corresponding sequence by one sample.

As an example, note that a causal FIR filter has as many poles as zeros, but all of them are at the origin $z=0$, i.e., they can't be used to shape the magnitude response. The same is true for an all-pole filter: all its zeros are at the origin, so they don't help to create a stop band (which would be one possible function of non-trivial zeros).

I think it's important to point out that the term *trivial zero* (or pole) is not a standard term used in DSP - as far as I know - but it appears to be an idiosyncratic use of a few authors.

Comment: the typical way in the literature to refer to something idiosyncratic , “so called trivial zeros”